# Lock is lost when putting ReentrantLock into HashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to make several consumer threads that listen to one producer thread wait until the producer has something to publish.  The code that I thought would work "loses" the lock on being put into and taken out of a shared class.

In a controller class I start the thread running with 
    Server server = new Server();

```
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(server,"Server");
    serverThread.start(); 

    Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
    Thread consumerThread;
    for (int i =0;i<6;i++){
        consumerThread = new Thread(consumer,"Consumer No:"+i);
    consumerThread.start();
    server.threadRefs[i]= consumerThread;
    }
```

The consumer classes put details of threads into the Map as follows:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition cond = lock.newCondition();

@Override
public void run() {

    long threadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    while (true) {
        try {

            lock.lock();

            MDRequest.threadLocks.put(threadID, lock);
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadID + "  lock = " + lock.toString());

            cond.await();
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadID + "  done waiting");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interruped " + threadID);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished " + threadID);
    }

}
```

The shared class is simply:

```
public class MDRequest {

    protected static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ReentrantLock> threadLocks = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ReentrantLock>();
```

The Server has the following run() method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Set<Long> keys = MDRequest.threadLocks.keySet();
    Long[] threadIDs = keys.toArray(new Long[1]);

    // generates a random series of numbers for each thread and notifies threads about them 
    while (true) {


        Random random = new Random();
        int threadRef = random.nextInt(5);

        System.out.println("About to signal thread " + threadIDs[threadRef].toString());

        // notify the thread of the data 
        ReentrantLock lock = MDRequest.threadLocks.get(threadIDs[threadRef]);
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadIDs[threadRef].toString() + "  lock = " + lock.toString());

        Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
        cond.signal();
        lock.unlock();

    }
```

The output is as follows:

```
Thread 11  lock = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@272d7a10[Locked by thread Consumer No:0]
Thread 12  lock = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@272d7a10[Locked by thread Consumer No:1]
Thread 13  lock = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@272d7a10[Locked by thread Consumer No:2]
Thread 14  lock = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@272d7a10[Locked by thread Consumer No:3]
Thread 15  lock = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@272d7a10[Locked by thread Consumer No:4]
Thread 16  lock = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@272d7a10[Locked by thread Consumer No:5]
About to signal thread 14
Thread 14  lock = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@272d7a10[Unlocked]
Exception in thread "Price Server" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1885)
    at faster.Server.run(Server.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

From the output int the Server class I can see that when I read the lock out of the Map it now has a status of "Unlocked".  When it was put in it had a status of Locked on thread 14.

Why does the reference to the ReentrantLock "lose" the lock?

Is there a way of sharing the lock between the multiple consumer threads and the server thread in a way that the lock is not lost?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem you are trying to solve, but I would seriously take a look at all the classes in the java.util.concurrent package.  Specifically the ThreadPoolExecutor: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is thread in `Server` class tries to unlock but has not lock the `Lock`

```
lock.unlock();
```

Please see [`ReentrantLock` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock()) where is clearly stated:

> If the current thread is not the holder of this lock then `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.   Do you know of a way I can signal() the consumer thread that should be awoken from the server thread?

Comment: You should share Condition instance that is used by the Consumers threads with server threads and donot create new one. For instance move the lock and condition to the shared class and in the server class just call cond.signal(). It is not necessary to use static variables to share object between classes. You can pass them in the constructor. Hope it helps, (I have limited time now sorry )

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is may be because of the following line in Server

```
Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
cond.signal();
lock.unlock();
```

Do you need to call `unlock()` from the `Server` for a `Lock` which is locked by the `Consumer`? I think calling `signal()` will suffice.

Think about this.

Comment: Futhermore - you can only unlock a re-entrant lock from the same thread that locked it.